# Is this considered bad practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm kind of combining javascript and jQuery here. It works, but is it bad practice?

```
<script> 
    var data = [];    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        data.forEach((function(d) {
            d.Hours = 40;
        }));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't worry so much about proper form.  Concern yourself more with readability.

Comment: This is a common practice, but yes it is not recommended. Here data is a `Global` variable, and you should avoid populating global scope. Try adding it in `IIFE`. This encapsulates you code and prevents global scope from contamination.

Comment: jQuery is a library written in JavaScript. Not sure how you'd *un*-combine them. There are other issues with your code (globals, indentation), but the use of both jQuery methods and other JavaScript functions is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If its not recommended, what is the best alternative? Also, regrding the global variable, are you suggesting I declare it inside the function? The problem with this is I have trouble debugging. What is IIFE? Oh and how do I upvote your post?

Comment: @BumSon IIFE stands for *immediately-invoked function expression*. [IIFE - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). And yes encapsulation variables inside a function is a better approach.

Comment: Thanks. What about debugging though? I guess I would have to use a breakpoint...